# Testflight Crash report not apprearing in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight, crash-reports

I uploaded my App to appstoreconnect with the organizer selected both, include symbols and include bitcode.
And then I distributed the App with TestFlight to internal Testers
I know that one tester had a crash and I can see the crash-feedback also in appstoreconnect.

But even 12 hours later the crash report did not appear in xcode organizer.

Is there any possibility to download and import the crash report from appstoreconnect?
It seems like I'm only able to download the crash feedback, which doesn't really help me.

Or do I have to change Settings for upload?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Still have same issues. The tester activated Sharing with Developers, but I'm still getting just the feedback, not the real crashlog. Any idea what I've got to do?

tester:
[image: tester]

feedback:
[image: feedback]

Comment: If you go to the AppStore connect, is there a stack trace? I mean, not only a .json, but also a crashlog? If no, did they have allowed in `Settings.app/Privacy/Analytics and Improvements` `Share iPhone` and `Share with App Developers`?

Comment: Thanke you! There is only the .json with the feedback. I checked my settings and saw that i did not allowed Sharing with Developers (read somewhere that this would be automatically for internal tester?)
Hope it works now!

Comment: Still dont recieve crashlog. Edited my post and added some pictures of my appstoreconnect view. Any idea what to do?

Comment: It might take a little time to appear in iTunes Connect if I recall correctly, it's not instant, I don't know the frequency check.

Comment: I wondered that the feedback is there, but there is no crash log. I thought they would appear at the same time. I'll have a look in the next hours

Comment: @joschuamarz did it work for you?